# Valor inválido: For input string:

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, chave-estrangeira

Erro ao fazer atualização, o valor do campo deve ser o código FK referente ao uma chave estrangeira, no INPUT do forme sai o valor br.com.tkcsapcd.model.bean.ProjetoInicio@7adacc20, no value="${termoAberturaProjeto.projetoinicio}" deve ser modificado alguma coisa?

**Código Projeto ***

```
                            <input id="projetoinicio" name="projetoinicio"
                                style="height: 30px; width: 300px"
                                Placeholder="" maxlength="150"
                                value="${termoAberturaProjeto.projetoinicio}" class="input" required="true"
                                onkeypress="return numbers(event);"></input>
                            <p class="hint">[Código do Projeto.]</p></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Como ta esse campo : projetoinicio no teu managed bean?

Comment: Estou trabalhando com JSP! @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="projetoinicio", nullable = false)
 private ProjetoInicio projetoinicio = new ProjetoInicio();

Comment: Atualmente você ta mostrando o objeto completo no value do campo , agora você precisa especificar algum cmapo do objeto ProjetoInicio para ser mostrado lá dentro.

Comment: Entendi! O problema esta sendo em especificar este campo do objeto no value="${termoAberturaProjeto.projetoinicio}" a chave estrangeira em JSP. Tentei de várias formas e está dando erro. Sabe como?

Comment: Esse termoAberturaProjeto é algum objeto? Ou atributo de algo que popula a jsp..

Se projetoinicio é um campo que tem dados então você pode fazer termoAberturaProjeto.projetoinicio.algumAtributo para recuperar os campos desse objeto.

Comment: termoAberturaProjeto é um Objeto. Quando tento recuperar o campo dar este erro: Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'Codigo' not found on type br.com.tkcsapcd.model.bean.ProjetoInicio

Comment: Diz que teu objeto ProjetoInicio não tem o campo Codigo .. Na hora de retornar o objeto você ta preenchendo ele?

Quais os campos que esse objeto possui..

Comment: Você gerou os getters e setters do campo 'codigo'?